# Bootstrap tooltip bug un-reproducible in Plunkr

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a weird CSS bug going on with bootstrap-ui tooltip:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlHHj.png

As you can see, the tooltip isn't directly above "aaa" as it should be.

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="tooltip_app">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('tooltip_app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    </script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class='container' id='results_container2'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <li class="list-group-item"><span tooltip="This is simply a really big really long tool tip longer and longer and longre This is simply a really big really long tool tip longer and longer and longre">aaa</span></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

However, if I literally copy and paste the file into plunkr the css bug goes away:

http://plnkr.co/edit/I5vFu5M8JRwRhK7kRBaL?p=preview

As you can see, everything works and is aligned as expected.

I'm banging my head here because I can't seem to reproduce the bug on jsfiddle or plunkr; it only appears when served by my node.js webserver. How is this possible? I'm using the same browser for both, and if plunkr and jsfiddle are as sandbox-y as they claim the results should be identical.

Comment: ctrl+shift+b will toggle your bookmark bar.

Comment: Just to be clear; when running on your local server, are you loading your assets (angular etc) from the same CDN, or from a local copy?

Comment: No, I'm running in incognito mode to avoid caching and I'm loading all of the assets from the urls in the `script` tags -- it's a literal copy-paste into plunker

Comment: I mean, can anyone else verify whether this bug exists by trying it out on their own node web server? I've tried it on two different computers, both running CentOS linux, node + express, and google chrome. The wierd thing is, if the tool tip is really short, it's aligned. As it gets longer, it drifts farther and farther up the page.